# Bootstrap Tabs for radio buttons information

Tags: javascript, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have a tabbed form, the entire thing is made in one form element, the idea is that different information is processed depending on which form the user submits from. I can use filter(), not() and classes to filter form results, but I need a way to "check" which tab is the active tab.

I also cannot use a different submit button or different form id's since the tabs are within another tab, which all submit to the same script

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="tabbable">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
        <p>Sides</p>
    <input type="radio" name="bread3" value="VanW" checked>White <br>
    <input type="radio" name="bread3" value="VanB">Brown
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
        <p>I'm in Section 2.</p>
        <div class="span8">
        <div class="tabbable tabs-left">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="active"><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Section 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">Section 4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab3">
            <p>Hamburger</p>
    <input type="radio" name="bread" value="VanW" checked>White <br>
    <input type="radio" name="bread" value="VanB">Brown
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
            <p>Pizza</p>
    <input type="radio" name="bread2" value="VanW" checked>White <br>
    <input type="radio" name="bread2" value="VanB">Brown
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the active tab, you can check which tab has the "active" class.

```
var $activeTab = $('.nav-tabs li.active');
```

You can then use it to get any other information you need.

```
var $activePanel = $($('a', $activeTab).attr('href'));
```

Or just look for the "active" class on the panel itself

```
var $activePanel = $('.tab-content>.active');
```

**Updated for only checking the inner tab**

If you know the tab is in tab2:

```
var $activeTab = $('#tab2 .nav-tabs li.active');
var $activePanel =  $('#tab2 .tab-content>.active');
```

If you only know it is a tab of an active tab:

```
var $activeTab = $('.tab-content>.active .nav-tabs li.active');
var $activePanel =  $('.tab-content>.active .tab-content>.active');
```

Comment: That makes sense, however considering this is a tab within a tab, how do I make sure it will only check the inner tab?

Comment: I just tried adding that to the javascript, var $activeTab = $('.nav-tabs li.active'); window.alert($activeTab.serialize()); but I can't seem to get any output out of it

Comment: The serialize() method only serializes items that would be sent to a form. The $activeTab is only the tab. Try the $activePanel.

Comment: Yes, I tried that too, window.alert just outputs [object Object]

Comment: I tried it and did not even get that much. According to the [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) documentation, unless you are serializing a whole form, you need to select the exact form controls. You should be able to select them like this `$(':input', $activePanel).serialize()`

Comment: Okay, that seems to work, somewhat, different panels give unique constant outputs. However the outputs themselves seem random, one tab always give out a blank for example. It might due to other parts of my code, what exactly does $(':input', $activePanel) do?

Comment: I want to get the activeTab to work, var $activeTab = $('#foodtab .nav-tabs li.active'); window.alert(String($activeTab)); which also only outputs Object Object, is there a way to get the href of the active tab?

Comment: $('a', $activeTab).attr('href') to get the href attribute. To answer your previous question, the :input selector selects form elements. See [reference](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector)

Comment: Okay, that seems to have worked, apparently the extra brackets around var $activePanel = $($('a', $activeTab).attr('href')) were the problem, $activePanel = $('a', $activeTab).attr('href') made it work, I'll work on it a bit more to see if any problems occur, thank you for your help